# Push a commit in two branches with Git

Tags: git, branch, push

how do I push a commit in two branches?

I can't use "git push", because then it pushes to three branches, and i just want the commit in two of them..

Ive tried a "git merge HEAD --commit id from branch A--" in branch B, but then it takes everything from branch A and merges with branch B. I just want the last commit and not everything else merged with branch B.

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Next time, make the commit on a different branch, starting from a common ancestor of branches A and B. That way you can merge it into both, and not end up with duplicate commits in the history.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

### Short answer

You can apply already existing commit to another branch using [`cherry-pick`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) command, and then push both branches using `git push origin branchA branchB`.

---

### Why pushing a commit in two branches might be useful

Assume you have a repository with this structure:

```
A--B--C--D  ← master ← HEAD
      \--E  ← v1-release
```

After some development (commits `A`, `B`, `C`) project was released and `v1-release` branch was created (so that v1 can be supported with bugfixes and next version can be developed in `master`). Commit `E` was used to specify version information (added release notes, etc). Commit `D` introduced new feature, which is planned for the next version and should not appear in `v1-release`.

Now, if a bug is found in `v1-release`, it must be fixed in both branches, so that users can continue using v1 and it does not appear in the next version.

After fixing the bug in `master`, repository should look like this:

```
A--B--C--D--F  ← master ← HEAD
      \--E     ← v1-release
```

Now commit `F` with a bugfix must be applied to `v1-release` branch.

## How to actually do it

Commits cannot be exactly copied (since commit is a directory saved state), but you can apply changes made in commit to another commit.

`cherry-pick` command does exactly that. It applies changes made by a specified commit to the current branch, creating new commit:

```
git checkout v1-release
git cherry-pick F
```

After this, repository should look like this:

```
A--B--C--D--F  ← master
      \--E--G  ← v1-release ← HEAD
```

Commit `G` introduces same changes as `F`.

You may have to resolve conflicts (exactly like after merge).

Error message

> The previous cherry pick was now empty ...

means that changes made by cherry-picked commit are already present in current branch. You probably forgot to checkout correct branch.

In case of errors or conflicts cherry-pick can be aborted using `git cherry-pick --abort`.

Finally, you can return to `master` branch and push both branches to remote repository:

```
git checkout master
git push origin master v1-release
```

Final repository structure:

```
A--B--C--D--F  ← master ← HEAD
      \--E--G  ← v1-release
```

Comment: What about pushing a local branch to two remote branches? Is there a short way to do that?

Comment: Example for cherry-pick command would be helpful to illustrate use in context and obviate need to digest a page of documentation.  Some of us can't RTFM as easily as others.. :)

Comment: you can also revert, stash and apply

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
git push origin <commitId>:<brancnName_1>
git push origin <commitId>:<brancnName_2>
```

It works on my side.

Comment: This is weird, I did this, and my commit disappeared from all logs. I can only see it in `git reflow`