# Commit to multiple branches at the same time with git

Tags: git

I have two branches A and B in a project that I am working on.  B differs from A by a single commit, which is a section of the code completely independent from what I'm working on for the next while (aka, I will have many commits I want to push to both branch A and B).

Is there any way in git that I can commit to both branch A and branch B at the same time, without having to commit it to one branch, checkout the other, and try to cherry pick out the commit(s).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push a commit in two branches with Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024095/push-a-commit-in-two-branches-with-git). It has a very good example with ASCII art.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: Commit to multiple branches at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259135/git-commit-to-multiple-branches-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could:

- make all your commits on `A`
- rebase `B` on top of `A` (if you haven't pushed B already, that is)

That way, `B` will include all commits from `A`, plus its single commit.

---

If you have shared `B` (pushed to a common remote repo), the idea is more to add any commit made on `A` to `B` (that is, "on top of `B`).

The simplest way would be to merge `A` on `B`, if you don't mind having only one commit on `B` representing all commits from `A`.
I would prefer that to any solution involving cherry-picking would mean different SHA1 for each commit recreated on `B`, which would make any future merge back to `A` complicated (because Git would go back a long way to find a common ancestor)

Comment: That would work, but I want to share B with some other people, so it needs to be public (and as such, I've already pushed it).  Thank you though anyway.

Answer (score 5):

the cherry-pick feature is a better way to do this, check answer at

[Git: Commit to multiple branches at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259135/git-commit-to-multiple-branches-at-the-same-time/18529576#18529576)