# Apply a commit to all children branches from parent branch?

Tags: git

I have some branches:

```
Branch A -> B
         -> C
         -> D
         -> E
```

I need to fix something on branch A, how am I able to apply the fix to all branches branched out from branch A without I need to cherrypick the fix to all branches B, C, D, and E?

Comment: There is no out-of-the box way to do this (I could be wrong). You will need to update all of the branches manually (whether it be rebasing, cherry-picking, or merging).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rebasing a branch including all its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600659/rebasing-a-branch-including-all-its-children)

Comment: Refer to [Commit to multiple branches at the same time with git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4532063/6521116)

Comment: As @Whymarrh says or patching. E.g. after the commit in A, when you are on B or C, etc, you can `git merge A` which will bring the changes from A. Or, you can create a patch form that commit and apply it, but it still needs to be applied individually to each of B, C, D, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Commit to multiple branches at the same time with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532063/commit-to-multiple-branches-at-the-same-time-with-git)

Comment: Is C a child branch of B, and D a child branch of C, and so on? This sounds odd. In any case, check out A, apply the commit, merge A into B, C, D, E, etc.

Comment: Oops sorry @LasseVågsætherKarlsen , please see my edited post

Comment: My comment still stands, check out A, apply the commit, merge A into B, C, D, E, etc.