# How do you handle a change that affects multiple versions in Git?

Tags: git, versioning

I am working at a place where we will have multiple versions of a product, each stored in their own branch. What is the proper methodology for merging a fix for a bug that might span multiple versions?

Also is branching the correct way to store multiple versions or should I somehow use tags? Sorry somewhat new to this advanced Git workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there are many ways to deal with it.
What I would do is to...

1. Create a new branch from master and fix this bug.

   ```
   git checkout master
   git checkout -b bugfix
   //git add some fix files
   git commit -m "bugfix with a better commit message"
   git push origin/bugfix
   ```
2. Merge into master.

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge bugfix
   git push origin/master
   ```
3. Everyone working on any other feature branches should:

   ```
   git checkout featureBranch
   //pull from master...
   git pull --rebase origin master
   ```

Comment: the only problem with this strategy is that the bug may not even exist in the master anymore. Lets say that from feature branch 2-6 the bug exists, but in no other, and we are now on 8. I know...its a tricky, and perhaps unanswerable problem. The answer might be, fix features 2-6 by hand.

Comment: Then fix this bug on branch 2 and [cherry-pick it onto branches 3-6](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18529576/4280359).

Comment: Thank you Sir! If you want, submit that as an answer (or just update your current answer with that). I didnt know about the Cherry Pick command.