# Git - How to automatically sync a file across all branches

Tags: git

I need to have one file/directory that will be sync for all the developers in all the branches **before** the developer is starting to work in any branch,

on moving to working branch **before starting work** (create branch, checkout/switch branch etc..)

1. switch to develop (this is the main branch of development, no developer should work on this branch)
2. update uniqueness files with user and working branch information
3. commit changes to develop
4. push commits of develop to remote
5. switch to working branch
6. checkout uniqueness files from develop
7. commit uniqueness files to working branch
8. start working on branch

What would be the best way of doing that?

Comment: You should commit a change to all branches, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7268236/6458908

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the developers will be working against an updated develop branch, keep the file/directory in the develop branch updated and ask every developer to rebase their working branch against the develop branch every time they start to work.

Comment: This would be my suggestion. It sounds like a dependency problem more than a source code versioning issue when I heard “every branch needs a file”

Comment: The trigger for the update of the files are when a developer is "stepping" to a branch, I want the update to be automatically and for the developer to have it in his working tree