# How to merge 2 branches during post-commit

Tags: git, githooks

I have a hair-splitting edge case where I need a commit to BranchA to be immediately merged into BranchB, and I'd like this to be automated.

I tried looking up steps to commit to 2 branches at the same time and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259135/commit-to-multiple-branches-at-the-same-time), but I don't know how to automate it.

I'm aware of `.git/hooks/post-commit` but I'm not sure if the commit exists before the hook runs or after the script exits 0. Also I don't know if the `git merge` command can merge to a branch we're not checked out too.

Is this something I can do with *just* git? Or do I need to invent a complicated rube-goldberg system of file-watchers?

Comment: "but I'm not sure if the commit exists before the hook runs or after the script exits 0" what happens when you _just try it_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm aware of `.git/hooks/post-commit` but I'm not sure if the commit exists before the hook runs ...

The commit *must* exist by this point.  What's not guaranteed is how you can *find* it.  The `HEAD` is updated, and any autostash has not yet been applied, so `HEAD` will generally work, but things aren't locked here so you could be competing with additional commits.

The more important part is this, though:

> Also I don't know if the `git merge` command can merge to a branch we're not checked out too.

This has a typo (or grammar-o) so I'm not 100% positive what you mean here, but I think you mean to ask whether `git merge` can merge *into* some branch other than the *current branch*, and the answer to that is simple: no, it cannot.

You *could* use an added working tree (see [the `git worktree` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)) to do what you want.  Use the existing working tree and `$GIT_DIR` to run `git rev-parse` to find the hash ID of the current commit (noting that you're racing against other potential `git commit` actions), then move to the other working tree, unset `GIT_WORK_TREE` if necessary, and do the merge there.  Remember that merges can fail, and won't start if the directory is not "clean".